# Magento 2.3 - How to verify US zip code with region in checkout and my account address

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, zipcode, usps

I want to verify if the zip code entered by the customer matches correctly with the region.

**For example:**

zip code:10001

Region: New york

If the customer enters the wrong zip code for the region, it throws an error **"your zipcode and region need to match"**

I think I need to use the USPS API.

I created an account in USPS API.

How to implement this functionality in the checkout page and my account save address page.

I followed this below link. But It doesn't work for me.

https://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-address-verification-using-usps-api-on-checkout/

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated

Comment: This is module is not good for  your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the postcode/Region  checking  at

`\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByExtendedAddress`
`\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::estimateByAddressId`

> because of these functions, the shipping methods are rendered at the
>   checkout page.

Note that, Magento 2 does not save the Shipping address till database 's quote until select the Shipping  method .

So, the above two methods is best way to checking ZipCode/region at checkout.

Comment: It is working fine.

Comment: How to show pop error message and stop to redirect to checkout page from cart page

Comment: If you want to show this message at pop  then you have work more and logic  will different from current.